# Subscribe and add-watch in uberjar

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I have component created with `reagent/create-class` which gets atom created by `subscribe`. I am adding a watch on `:component-did-mount` in order to call component (js) function on request, which is triggered by change in the atom (there is a server round trip). It looks somewhat as following:

```
(defn editor [text issue-hints]
  (let []
    (reagent-core/create-class
     {:component-did-mount
      #(let [editor      (js/SimpleMDE.
                          (clj->js {...}))]
         (do
           ...
           (add-watch issue-hints :watch-issue-hints (show-hint (-> editor .-codemirror)))
           ...))
      :reagent-render
      (fn [this] [:textarea])})))

(defn edit-panel [text]
  (let [test (re-frame.core/subscribe [:issue-hints])]
    [box
     :class "issue-detail"
     :size "auto"
     :child [:div.issue-detail [editor text test]]]))
```

It works well when debugging the project, but once uberjar file is run, watch handler never gets called. What is the most strange thing to me is that if at least dummy reference to subscription atom is added, it works well again (eg. `dummy @issue-hints` in same let as subscription). Server round trip looks good.

Can someone give me explanation and/or suggestion for more reasonable fix/workaround?

Comment: Have you compiled the ClojureScript differently when running the uberjar?

Comment: Yes, I would say so, especially if you mean `:optimizations`, but none of my experiments helped me. If it somehow helps, [here](https://github.com/jhamrsky/memory-hole/tree/cross-link-issues) is branch I am working on - relevant/critical part is [here](https://github.com/jhamrsky/memory-hole/blob/c4c690dd24cf23cf8be78d8ec81a28292be3a259/src/cljs/memory_hole/pages/issues.cljs#L55).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need two params in `:reagent-render`, not one -

```
:reagent-render
  (fn [text issue-hints] [:textarea])}))) ---> Not "this", but should match initial args
```

When you only pass one arg, and it is not derefed in the `component-did-mount` fn, it won't receive the subscription on subsequent changes.

Further, I don't think that you need to explicitly use `add-watch`, as that is what the `re-frame` subscription is giving you ootb. By using the deref syntax `@issue-hints`, the element will be notified any time a change happens to `issue-hints`, and you should be able to watch the state from the `app-db`.

If you add the 2nd arg, my guess is that you could drop the `add-watch` and it should work as expected.

Here are the [docs](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/CreatingReagentComponents.md#form-3-a-class-with-life-cycle-methods) and if you look at the code sample, you see the repetition of the args...

`----- Edit: Will Form-2 work? -----`

```
(defn editor [text issue-hints]
  (let [hints @issue-hints
        editor (js/SimpleMDE. (clj->js {...})] ;;-> This will not be dynamic, so consider moving to returned fn if necessary
    (fn [text issue-hints]
       (if hints
          [:textarea (special-hint-handler hints)]
          [:textarea]
    ))))
```

So based on the comments, this would give you a `watcher` on `issue-hints`, and you could respond accordingly. The subscription does not necessarily need to be used on the DOM.

Comment: Thats a good catch, I missed that one. Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem and still watch handler is not called. I am using `add-watch` as kind of request firing event and `issue-hints` (or their derefferenced value) are not actually rendered directly in UI. Is there somewhere documented, that `add-watch` needs in such cases to have previously dereferenced atom in order to work (did not find it myself)?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure that I am fully understanding what you are trying to accomplish. `Form-3` forms are used for complex components which have local state. In this case, it seems that they might be the wrong tool, b/c the `:component-did-mount` is a DOM rendering. You might consider switching to `Form-2` and fire a function when the signal changes. That is, the derefered subscription does not require a reference to the DOM. (will update code above, and apologies if I am misunderstanding)

Comment: Based on the [subscription flow documentation](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/SubscriptionFlow.md) I've put deref of `issue-hints` into `:reagent-render` as part of `do` block and it now works as it should. I guess my case is just a little bit special for re-frame.

Comment: Great! Glad it is sorted.